# SSL issues with jinja HTTPS load balancer - Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, jinja2, load-balancing, google-deployment-manager

I have been able to deploy this load balancer as a HTTP load balancer, and am now trying to deploy this as a HTTPS load balancer. I am attempting this with .JUNJA and .YAML on Google Cloud.

I keep getting the error: `Invalid value for field 'resource.sslCertificates[0]': 'www.example.com'. The\\ URL is malformed.`

```
resources:
  - name: web-lb-hc #Create a health check for the backend
    type: compute.v1.httpsHealthCheck
    properties:
      port: 443
      requestPath: /

  - name: web-url-map #Required to map url to backend
    type: compute.v1.urlMap
    properties:
      defaultService: $(ref.backend.selfLink)

  - name: backend
    type: compute.v1.backendService #Deployment of backend for VM's 
    properties:
      port: 443
      portName: https
      protocol: HTTPS #Defeined HTTP port for communication with backends
      backends:
      - name: backend
        balancingMode: UTILIZATION
        capacityScaler: 1.0
        group: $(ref.web-ins-group.selfLink)
      maxUtilization: 0.8
      connectionDraining:
        drainingTimeoutSec: 300
      healthChecks: 
      - $(ref.web-lb-hc.selfLink)

  - name: web-http-proxy
    type: compute.v1.targetHttpsProxy
    properties:
      urlMap: $(ref.web-url-map.selfLink)
      sslCertificates: ["www.example.com"]
  - name: web-ipaddress
    type: compute.v1.globalAddress

  - name: web-http-forwardingrule #Creation of forwarding rule 
    type: compute.v1.globalForwardingRule
    properties:
      target: $(ref.web-http-proxy.selfLink)
      IPAddress: $(ref.web-ipaddress.address)
      IPProtocol: TCP #Chosen protocol
      portRange: 443-443
```

Any help with this would be much appriciated!

Answer (score 1):

sslCertificates is an array of urls.

To determine the url for an SSL certificate follow these steps.

Get a list of SSL certificates:

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates list
```

Get the details for the SSL certificate:

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates describe NAME
```

In the returned data near the bottom look for selfLink. This is the value you want to use. This value will look like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/development/global/sslCertificates/production-lb
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @JohnHanley, the command `compute ssl-certificates describe NAME` results in `-bash: compute: command not found`? I change the `NAME` to the name of the SSL name and tried it with just `NAME`, but both result in the same error.

Comment: @user10190803 I fixed the command adding `gcloud` to the command example.