# Need to know the format of the SSL Certificate URL in GCP setSSLCertificates call

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-network-load-balancer

I want to set the SSL certificate used by a GCP target SSL proxy using the api call that looks like:

https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/global/targetSslProxies/{resourceId}/setSslCertificates

However, this call requires an sslCertificate argument in the request body, and this is described as a string which contains:

"New set of URLs to SslCertificate resources to associate with this TargetSslProxy. Currently exactly one ssl certificate must be specified."

But I can't find where it explains what a "URL to SslCertificate" looks like. If you use the certificate name in GCP, it gives a malformed URL error.

Does anyone know what this URL is supposed to look like?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54962905/8016720

Comment: Using the url from selfLink is indeed the correct answer. Thanks very much for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I’m reading about your issue, i think you are setting pp SSL Proxy Load Balancing.

The official documentation to create an [SSL Proxy Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl/setting-up-ssl) is very complete, for my part I have completed all instructions and it works well.

It’s probably you are talking about this section “Configure your SSL certificate resources”.

You can create the self-signed certificates using this page “[Working with self-managed SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#working-self-managed)”, before create an SSL Certificate.

Regards.

Comment: No, that documentation just talks about how to do it from the console and gcloud, not from the API.

Comment: In the same page you can choose to use gcloud or console (API), you need select this tab and all examples change for use the selected. 
 [1] https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl/setting-up-ssl